# react native modal takes 2 second to open

Tags: react-native, expo

In my app you can join a group. There are storys and messages. If there is no story or messages modal is open fast. But If I have 30 text messages to render and want to click to open my modal then it takes 1-2 seconds or later to open. The same issue if I click a button. The opacity and function works until 1-2 seconds but if there is no much messages to render then it goes fast. I need help.

message render function

```
          <FlatList
            data={globalMessages}
            style={{width: '100%'}}
            contentContainerStyle={{marginLeft: 12}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => deleteMessage(item.id)} style={{width: 230, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#eee', padding: 8, borderRadius: 12, margin: 12, marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0}}>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-light', fontSize: 16, color: '#333'}}>{item.message}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-medium', fontSize: 12, color: '#333'}}>{item.date}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
           // ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
            horizontal={false}
            nestedScrollEnabled
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            // Performance settings
            removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window 
            initialNumToRender={2} // Reduce initial render amount
            maxToRenderPerBatch={1} // Reduce number in each render batch
            updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
            windowSize={4} // Reduce the window size
            />
```

fullCode:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions, ImageBackground, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, FlatList, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import uploadStoryAPI from '../api/uploadStory';
import createMessageAPI from '../api/createMessage';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const Room = ({ route }) => {
  const socket = io('http://192.168.0.249:3000', {
    transports: ['websocket']
  });

  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [areaHeight, setAreaHeight] = useState(0);
  const [chatMessage, setChatMessage] = useState('');
  const [globalMessages, setGlobalMessages] = useState(route.params.messages || []);
  const [loadSendChatMessage, setLoadSendChatMessage] = useState(false);
  const [alignItem, setAlignItem] = useState('center');
  const [addStory, setAddStory] = useState(false);
  const [storys, setStorys] = useState(route.params.storys || []);
  const [modalImagePreview, setModalImagePreview] = useState(false);
  const [modalDeleteMessage, setModalDeleteMessage] = useState(false);
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = useState('');
  const [loadUpload, setLoadUpload] = useState(false);
  const [sourceStory, setSourceStory] = useState({
    uri: null,
    type: null,
    name: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      setConnected(true);
      console.log('user connected');
    });

    socket.on('getmessage', message => {
      globalMessages.length > 0 ?
      setGlobalMessages(prevState => {
        return [...prevState, message]
      }) : setGlobalMessages([message]);
      handleAddMessage();
    });
  });

  const handleAlign = () => {
    areaHeight > 100 ? setAlignItem('flex-end') : setAlignItem('center'); 
  }

  const handleAddStory = async () => {
    try {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [1, 1]
      });
      setAddStory(false);

      if(result.cancelled) {
        setAddStory(false);
        return;
      }

      let localUri = result.uri;
      let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();
    
      // Infer the type of the image
      let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
      let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

      setImagePreview(localUri);
      setSourceStory({
        uri: localUri,
        type,
        filename
      });
      setModalImagePreview(true);
    } catch(e) {
      return;
    } 
  };

  const handleUploadToServer = async () => {
    try {
      setLoadUpload(true);
      let res = await uploadStoryAPI(route.params.roomID, sourceStory);
      res.upload && storys.length > 0 
      ? setStorys(prevState => {
        return [{
          source: res.source
        }, ...prevState]
      }) : setStorys([{ source: res.source}]);
      console.log(`D ${storys}`)
      res.upload ? (setLoadUpload(false),setModalImagePreview(false)) : setLoadUpload(false);
    } catch(e) {
      return e;
    }
  };

  const handleAddMessage = async () => {
    try {
      setLoadSendChatMessage(true);
      const res = await createMessageAPI(route.params.roomID, chatMessage);
      console.log(res);
      //scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
      setLoadSendChatMessage(false);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    }
  };
  
  const deleteMessage = async id => {
    try {
      console.log(id);
    } catch(e) {
      return e;
    }
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" style={{margin: 0, padding: 0}}>
      <View style={{height: height - 155, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <View>
        <ScrollView>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Storys</Text>
          {
            storys.length > 0 
            ?
            <FlatList
            data={storys}
            contentContainerStyle={{marginLeft: 8}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={`index-${item.source}`} style={{padding: 0, marginRight: 16, borderWidth: 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 100, borderColor: '#1ab7ff', height: 68, width: 68}}>
              <Image resizeMode="contain" source={{uri: `http://192.168.0.249:3000/build/${item.source}`}} style={{height: 55, width: 55, borderRadius: 500}} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.source.toString()}
           // ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
            nestedScrollEnabled
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            // Performance settings
            removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window 
            initialNumToRender={2} // Reduce initial render amount
            maxToRenderPerBatch={1} // Reduce number in each render batch
            updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
            windowSize={7} // Reduce the window size
            />
            :
            <Text>Es sind zurzeit keine Storys vorhanden.</Text>
          }
          <Text style={styles.title}>Nachrichten</Text>
        {
          globalMessages.length > 0
           ?
          <FlatList
            data={globalMessages}
            style={{width: '100%'}}
            contentContainerStyle={{marginLeft: 12}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => deleteMessage(item.id)} style={{width: 230, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#eee', padding: 8, borderRadius: 12, margin: 12, marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0}}>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-light', fontSize: 16, color: '#333'}}>{item.message}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-medium', fontSize: 12, color: '#333'}}>{item.date}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
           // ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
            horizontal={false}
            nestedScrollEnabled
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            // Performance settings
            removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window 
            initialNumToRender={2} // Reduce initial render amount
            maxToRenderPerBatch={1} // Reduce number in each render batch
            updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
            windowSize={4} // Reduce the window size
            />
            : null
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: 16, paddingTop: 8, paddingRight: 16, paddingBottom: 12, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: alignItem, justifyContent:'space-between', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setAddStory(true)}>
          <AntDesign name="pluscircleo" size={32} color="#444" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={e => setChatMessage(e)} 
         // onFocus={() => setAlignItem('flex-end')}
          onEndEditing={() => handleAlign()}
          value={chatMessage}
          multiline={true}
          style={[styles.input, {height: Math.max(50, areaHeight)}]}
          onContentSizeChange={e => {
            setAreaHeight(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height);
          }}
          placeholder="Gebe eine Nachricht ein..." />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => chatMessage.length > 0 ? socket.emit('getmessage', {
          chatMessage,
          date: Date.now()
          }) : null} style={{padding: 8, paddingRight: 10, borderRadius: 8, backgroundColor: '#1ab7ff'}}>
         { !loadSendChatMessage ? <Ionicons name="paper-plane-outline" size={28} color="#fff" /> : <ActivityIndicator style={{height: 20, width: 20}} color="#fff" />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      { /* Ask user if he wants to upload */}
      <Modal
        isVisible={modalImagePreview}
        swipeDirection="down"
        onSwipeComplete={() => setModalImagePreview(false)}
        onBackButtonPress={() => setModalImagePreview(false)}
        onBackdropPress={() => setModalImagePreview(false)}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
        // style={{margin: 0, padding: 0}}
      >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 12, padding: 12}}>
          <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-light', color: '#333', fontSize: 18, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 10}}>Möchtest du diese Story hochladen?</Text>
         {  <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{height: 250, borderRadius: 12}} source={{uri: imagePreview}} />  }
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 10}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalImagePreview(false)}>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-light', color: '#333', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#eee', padding: 10, paddingTop: 13, borderRadius: 8}}>Abbrechen</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleUploadToServer()} style={{backgroundColor: '#1ab7ff', padding: 10, paddingTop: 13, borderRadius: 8}}>
              { !loadUpload ? <Text style={{fontFamily: 'poppins-light', color: '#fff'}}>Story hinzufügen</Text> : <ActivityIndicator style={{height: 20, width: 20}} color="#fff" /> }
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      { /* Modal open Story */ }
      <Modal
        isVisible={addStory}
        swipeDirection="down"
        onSwipeComplete={() => setAddStory(false)}
        onBackButtonPress={() => setAddStory(false)}
        onBackdropPress={() => setAddStory(false)}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
        style={{margin: 0, padding: 0}}
      >
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 20}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddStory()} style={{padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#1ab7ff', width: width, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 20}}>
            <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontFamily: 'poppins-light'}}>Story hinzufügen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setAddStory(false)} style={{padding: 20}}>
            <Text>Abbrechen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  )
};
```

Comment: have you tried commenting out flatlist props under Performance settings?

Comment: how I do this ? and the flatlist performance settings not work on global messages. But in story it works. I also get the error message: Virutallist should never be nested....

Comment: the error message is because of FlatList is inside ScrollView, which should be avoided for performance issues

Comment: But I need KeyboardAwarescrollView because at the bottom I have a chat bar like whatsapp. And I have story flatlist and message flatlist. How I fix this?